# Connecting to MySQL on AWS RDS with SSL pem keys

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-aurora

I set up a new MySQL instance on AWS RDS (Aurora). I added a user that requires SSL, and downloaded the combined ca bundle as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and here: [SSL Connection error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), and I can connect via command line and confirm that the user is securely connected. I also turned off the SSL requirement for the user temporarily and was able to connect with MySQL Workbench with SSL turned off.
The problem is that both MySQL Workbench and my Rails app expect three separate files: SSL CA, SSL Cert, and SSL Key. 
I'm sure there has to be an easy solution to it, but much Googling is not finding the answer, including [this unanswered one on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230304). I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any other files. When it comes to the MySQL Workbench you need to provide "SSL CA File" and "Use SSL" ("Require" or "Require and Verify CA").

After that you can verify your connection by using the following command:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
```

Comment: That did the trick. For reference, I also tried it in my database.yml file for Rails and put the combined cert path on the sslca line and removed the sslkey and sslcert lines and was able to connect. Thanks for the help!